# Accessing SNTP MD5 Authorized Time Sync Server through GPO

Tags: windows-server, ntp, group-policy

I am running a Windows Server 2008 R2 server network connected to a Hardware Time Sync Server with MD5 authentication enabled. All the servers and clients are configured through NTP as NTP clients to point to the Time Sync Server.

I want to make sure the clients continue to check in. However, as I look through the Windows Time Service portion of GPO I can't find anything that will allow me to input the MD5 key and method so the client can securely connect to it.

Is there something I am missing to get this done? I have googled for this issue but I can't find any information that Windows Server can't set MD5 security SNTP connection. Has anyone done this and know the options to do so?